# Return mongoid object as json.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am trying to build an api with mongoid and rails. 
When I return an object as a json , it partially works but as an _id
returns a hash object

```
render :json => @object

{"_id":{"$oid":"536faac8506574fb87000000"},"address":"Test address.","lat":0.0,"lon":0.0,"name":"Test Name"}
```

shouldn't be returning "_id": "536faac8506574fb87000000"

How can I do that ?

Comment: How about using rabl gem for api?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply change this behavior in `as_json` method:

```
module MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document

  def as_json(*args)
    res = super

    # convert BSON::ObjectId to string
    res["_id"] = res["_id"].to_s

    # or you also can change attribute name from _id to id
    # res["id"] = res.delete("_id").to_s

    res
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is using helper function as below

```
 render :json => custom_json(@object)

 private
 def custom_json(value)
   result = value.map do |client|
     { :id => " #{client.id}",
       :address => client.address.to_s,
       :name => client.name.to_s
     }
   end
   result.to_json
 end
```